# Angular 7 and External Java Script file errors

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building an SPA in Angular for the first time and I have an issue with my app-video-controls component that I built.

I prototyped the app in HTML and the vanilla javascript worked great however when I rebuilt in Angular and imported the same js file, I started getting an error:

> Cannot set property 'currentTime' of null

here's the Profile.Component.html

```
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let user of users">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="account-item clearfix">
                    <div class="image">  <a href="#">
                            <img 
                            [src]="user.imagePath" 
                            alt="{{user.name}}">
                          </a></div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>{{user.name}}</h1>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row" *ngFor="let user of users">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 id="tag">Video</h2>
            <video id="my-video" class="video-js video1" controls="" preload="auto" width="100%">
                    <source id="source_video" [src]="user.videoPath" type="video/mp4">
                    <p class="vjs-no-js">
                     To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                    <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                    </p>
                    </video>

        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2>Sections</h2>
        <app-video-controlls></app-video-controlls>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h2>Comments</h2>
                <div class="comments">

                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</td>
```

Heres the video-controls.component.html

```
<div class="Section1">

<button id="video1" class="video-btn playing">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></div>
        <div class="video-text"><strong>Section 1. Introduction and Warm up</strong><br>
           </div>
    </button>
    <div id="timestamp-1" class="list">
        <ul>
            <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime()" type="button">What is your name?</button></li> 
            <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime2()" type="button">What do you study?</button></li>
            <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime3()" type="button">How did you develop this interest in linguistics?</button></li>
            <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime4()" type="button">What do you do for fun?</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

            <button id="video2" class="video-btn "> 
                <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></div>
                <div class="video-text"><strong>Section 2. Academic Discussion</strong><br>
            Discussion based on information provided</div>
        </button>
        <div id="timestamp-2" class="list inactive">
                <ul>
                        <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime5()" type="button">Argument For Solar Energy</button></li> 
                        <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime6()" type="button">Argument For Bike Paths</button></li>
                        <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime7()" type="button">What were the two ideas?</button></li>
                        <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime8()" type="button">Which idea should be implemented first?</button></li>
                        <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime9()" type="button">Safety concerns?</button></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            <button id="video-3" class="video-btn">
                <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></div>
                <div class="video-text"><strong>Section 3. Academic Presentation</strong><br>
                    Questions based on an academic lecture</div></button>
                    <div id="timestamp-3" class="list inactive">
                            <ul>
                                    <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime10()" type="button">Summarize the video you viewed on cave paintings.</button></li> 
                                    <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime11()" type="button">Have you ever taken an art class?</button></li>
                                    <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime12()" type="button">Do you think there should be more art classes in primary schools?</button></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>

                <button id="video-4" class="video-btn"> <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></div>
                    <div class="video-text"><strong>Section 4. Free Discussion</strong><br>
                       Interviewee talks about any topic they like</div> </button>
                       <div id="timestamp-4" class="list inactive">
                            <ul>
                                    <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime13()" type="button">Experience living in a foreign country</button></li> 
                                    <li class="question"><button onclick="setCurTime11()" type="button">What did you notice about different cultures living abroad?</button></li>

                                </ul>
                        </div>
</div>
```

Snippet of the angular.json file

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "src/app/js/video.js"
        ],
```

and finally a snippet of the js

```
var vid = document.getElementById("my-video");

function getCurTime() { 
 alert(vid.currentTime);
} 

function setCurTime() { 
  vid.currentTime=14;
}
```

Comment: did you install jquery by npm install jquery — save ?

Comment: The snippet of js, is that taken from your angular component or from where? if you gonna set something on an element in the DOM use the ViewChild to get it. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild or use the setters/getters, don't know if currentTime is supported

Comment: Your file Profile.Component.html contains a row for each user, so you end up having multiple elements with id 'my-video'. This is invalid DOM and should be avoided, you'll never be able to getElementById on it

Comment: @HienNguyen npm install